# DLookUp Function not match

Tags: database, ms-access

Why when I write code like this the result doesn't match the table?
Code:

```
=DLookUp("Quiz","Grade_Fall_2022","Program_ID= '" & DLookUp("ID","Program","Program= '" & [Text_Program1] & "'") & "'" And "TIS_ID= " & [Text_ID])
```

Result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/c84Xh.png

Source Table: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aywZE.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with:

```
=DLookUp("Quiz","Grade_Fall_2022","Program_ID = '" & DLookUp("ID","Program","Program = '" & [Text_Program1] & "'") & "' And TIS_ID = " & [Text_ID])
```

Comment: wow that's work thank you very much Gustav